# Precision of a model in training (balanced dataset) versus production (imbalanced dataset)

Tags: machine-learning

I have a balanced dataset used for model training purposes. There are two classes. My model has a precision of 50%, meaning that for 100 samples it predicts that 50 are positive, of those 50 only 25 *are* actually positive. The model is basically as good as flipping a coin.

Now in production, the data is highly unbalanced, say only 4 out of 100 samples are positive. Will my model still have the same precision?

The way I understand it is that my coin-flip model would then label 50 samples as positive, of which only 2 would actually be positive so precision would be 4% (2/50) in production.

Is it true that a model that was trained on a balanced dataset would have a different precision in production?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends: of those 50 samples classified as positive, are all 25 true positive samples correctly classified?
If your model correctly predicts every positive sample as positive and then also negative samples as positive (high sensitivity, low specificity), I think your precision would be at around 8%. Nevertheless, you should revisit your training, since fpr 50% precision you don't need a ML model but rather a one-liner generating a random variable between 0 and 1.

Comment: Thanks @Noltibus. Agreed - the model is terrible and a random variable generator would perform equally well. Fortunately this is not a real-world example. At the heart of my question is this: For a given model, will the precision be different for a balanced versus imbalanced dataset?

Comment: If the model is completely random and will judge 50 samples as positive and 50 examples as negative and you have a completely imbalanced dataset which consists only of positive samples (for example), then yes, the precision will be different compared to a balanced dataset.

Comment: Thank you! Yes - so precision is a feature of the model _and_ the dataset, not just the model. I guess that's the answer I was looking for.